# Дублирование произвольных полей WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Создал руками произвольное поле для записи в админке WordPress. Указал его месторасположение в правом сайдбаре. Однако по факту поле дублируется в блоке произвольных полей, которые предоставляет сам движок.
Можно ли этого как-то избежать, чтобы поля существовали отдельно?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 function test_additional_post_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'additional_post_box',
        'My text 1',
        'test_show_metabox',
        'kolba',
        'side',
        'low'
    );
}

add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'test_additional_post_box');

$meta_fields = array(
    array(
        'label' => 'My text 1',
        'id'    => 'kolbamytextarea',
        'type'  => 'textarea'
    )
);

//show additional metabox
function test_show_metabox() {
    global $meta_fields;
    global $post;

    echo '<input type="hidden" name="custom_meta_box_nonce" value="'.wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)).'" />';

    echo '<table class="form-table">';
    foreach ($meta_fields as $field) {

        $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);
        switch($field['type']) {
            case 'textarea':
                echo '<textarea name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" cols="60" rows="4" style="width: 90%">'.$meta.'</textarea> 
                        <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';
                break;
        }
        echo '</td></tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
}

// save additional metabox
function test_save_meta_fields($post_id) {
    global $meta_fields;

    if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['custom_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__)))
        return $post_id;

    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
        return $post_id;

    if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {
        if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id))
            return $post_id;
    } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    foreach ($meta_fields as $field) {
        $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);
        $new = $_POST[$field['id']];
        if ($new && $new != $old) {
            update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);
        } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {
            delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);
        }
    }
}

add_action('save_post', 'test_save_meta_fields');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рабочий код

```
function test_additional_post_box() {
    // Отображение на записях и страницах
    $screens = array( 'post', 'page' );
    foreach ( $screens as $screen ){
        add_meta_box(
            'kolba_post_box',
            'My text 1',
            'test_show_metabox',
            $screen,
            'side',
            'low'
        );
    }
}

add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'test_additional_post_box');

//show additional metabox
function test_show_metabox($post, $metabox) {
    $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, "_kolbamytextarea", true);

    echo '<input type="hidden" name="kolba_meta_box_nonce" value="'.wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)).'" />';

    echo '<textarea name="kolbamytextarea" id="kolbamytextarea" cols="60" rows="4" style="width: 90%">'.$meta.'</textarea> 
                        <br /><span class="description">Description</span>';
}

// save additional metabox
function test_save_meta_fields($post_id) {

    if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['kolba_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__)))
        return $post_id;

    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
        return $post_id;

    if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {
        if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id))
            return $post_id;
    } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    $my_data = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['kolbamytextarea'] );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_kolbamytextarea', $my_data );
}

add_action('save_post', 'test_save_meta_fields');
```

https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_meta_box

Comment: Отлично работает. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте перед именем поля символ подчеркивания: `_kolbamytextarea`. Тогда поле станет скрытым, и не будет отображаться стандартными средствами WordPress. В то же время вы сможете с ним работать в своём коде.

Comment: Работает. Спасибо